# Annoying message 'Building workspace' on status bar after I version controlled a project

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 (Build id: 20140612-0600)

I added my first project to version in Eclipse using EGit, but I'm seeing an annoying message on the bottom status bar saying 'Building workspace' from every 10 seconds or so. I really have no idea why this is happening. The only thing that I know is that I can't live with this because it is annoying and distracting. If I can't fix this I will use git in the command line and abandon EGit.

How can I get rid of this?

Marcos

Comment: Do you use Eclipse's Maven integration by any chance? Also, check if there are any uncommitted changes (look in the *Git Staging* view for this).

Comment: I don't use Maven at all and there aren't any uncommited changes (I've already checked that).

Comment: The problem with a problem like this is that we have no idea why the workspace is being built. There should be an easy way to verify why the building of the workspace is being triggered. I've spent the last two weeks studying git and EGit to use it for the first time and now I'm stuck with this issue.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you disconnect the project (context menu > Team > Disconnect)?

Comment: @robinst Yes, it goes away if I do that.

Comment: To debug this, run `jstack <pid>` (you can use `jps` to find out the pid) while it's building (timing must be right), and paste the output somewhere.

Comment: I've already debugged it with Eclipse. See this discussion: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/790020/

Comment: Ah, would have been nice to link these to each other from the start.. I now noticed the same flashing of the message (never noticed that before), will look into it soon.

Comment: Seems to be a problem in the platform :/. See [bug 439325](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439325).

Comment: I added my workaround in [bug 439325](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439325)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after deleting files that where shared resolution was:
uncheck the project -> build project automatically
then clean all the workspace.
for now it works.